# Bootstrap 4 custom header css (logo on left with title at it's right and icons under the title)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 and I'm trying to get the left of my header to look like this:

[image]

The html i've done is this below but i'm stuck here:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="./images/logo.png" alt="">
      <span>TITLE HERE</span>
    </a>
   <div>
     <img src="./images/icon1.png" alt="" />
     <img src="./images/icon2.png" alt="" />
     <img src="./images/icon3.png" alt="" />
     <img src="./images/icon4.png" alt="" />
     <img src="./images/icon5.png" alt="" />
  </div>
 </div>
</nav>
```

How can I get something similar to the image above?

Comment: How does your screen look now? You posted the expected behavior but what is the actual behavior you get with posted html?

Comment: The logo and title are in their place but the images below don't even show up

Comment: I don't see the problem you mentioned. All opened div's are closed

Comment: sorry, i read it wrong because of the improper indent.

Comment: No worries...yeah it needed indenting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### About your images

---

You don't need to define height on each img, there must be a problem on some custom CSS or in your image path... maybe give us any more info we need to know, what's the styling of your nav ?

[Here](https://codepen.io/hotlinedelite/pen/poEgXGo), as you can see, i tried your code and the images are

You can see that each img line is formed like this :

```
<img height="32" src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fcdn.onlinewebfonts.com%2Fsvg%2Fimg_275609.png" alt="" />
```

And if you remove it, you'll see that the image appears in full size !

#### About the second line in the navbar

---

In your code, there is a full width container which is `container-fluid` div.
You need to close that down to start a new line :

```html
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img src="./images/logo.png" alt="">
          <span>TITLE HERE</span>
        </a>
      </div> <!-- Here the line ends -->
       <div> <!-- THIS div in now under the container -->
         <img src="./images/icon1.png" alt="" />
         <img src="./images/icon2.png" alt="" />
         <img src="./images/icon3.png" alt="" />
         <img src="./images/icon4.png" alt="" />
         <img src="./images/icon5.png" alt="" />
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: In your solution the icons go all the way to the right. I need them under the title

Comment: @z4nzi Does this answer the question? If yes, please explain what is the fix? If no, please consider asking for more details in comments section.

Comment: I updated the pen : you need to close the container div.
The class of this container is `container-fluid` and it is takes full width of the screen. Closing it is like starting a new line. See : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/overview/#fluid
I will edit my answer in this way.